# How to get the current user in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am writing app that has a few search selections in a drop down. I need to be able to save those selections for every user that uses the app. I am not sure on how to get the current user. My app uses MVVM architecture and AngularJS. I am using C#, .net and sql server

Comment: what have you tried so far? are you saving it in your backend?

Comment: It all depends on your authentication framework.

Comment: Well, I am looking for a way to get the user in the code side using javascript and angularJS before saving the selections. I have tried-
 var currentUser = User.Identity.Name;
<input type="text"  id="currentUser" name="currentUser" value='@currentUser' /

int value;
value=WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
<p>Current User ID is: @value</p>--> 
@AlekseySolovey,

Comment: @rabyusbeef what kind of selecting are you looking for? can you describe how you expect it to work?

Comment: Basically I have 3 selections that have a dropdown list. When a user logs into the app. I want the app to save the selections the user makes from those 3 selections into the database. @AlekseySolovey

Comment: @rabyusbeef how about [this example](https://plnkr.co/edit/rvF86VL4mNZpONLC0lkC?p=preview)

Comment: yes, I think that's what I am looking for. Thank you @AlekseySolovey

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I ahve a controller and a service in my app.  Where would the respective lines of code that you have in the link go?

Comment: @rabyusbeef controller is responsible for binding variables to $scope in order to render them in your view (html). Service is a collection of methods (just for convenience). Your job is to bind selections to $scope (with `ng-model`) and send them to your backend with `$http.post(url,data)` (along with user info / ID). The rest is irrelevant (I tried to display your `User.Identity.Name` and such)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I am getting the following error 
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'myCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: @rabyusbeef you should learn the basics first (go through [tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_intro.asp)). Rename the controller to match yours. E.g. `ng-controller="myCtrl"` and `app.controller("myCtrl", ...)`. Additionally you might be missing dependancies: `angular.module("...")` -> `angular.module("...", [])`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Ok, I will but I have to finish this requirement soon. I am not able to get the current user that has logged into my app still.

Comment: @rabyusbeef it depends on the **backend** (you haven't described it yet). With PHP, for example, you can have a [session](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) (or even cookies), which you can `echo` to your front-end and receive with something like `$http.get(url).then((res)=>{$scope.user = res.data;})`

Answer (score 0):

for accessing from everywhere in the application, you can use a service that use localstorage. In the localstorage, you can keep all the data.
see [this](https://github.com/wooptoo/ngStorage) for localstorage and [this](https://www.airpair.com/javascript/posts/services-in-angularjs-simplified-with-examples) for writing a service.

Comment: if it helped you, please mark it as selected answer and upvote it ;)

Comment: It did not help, sorry